# Freeing a dyanamic array by passing it to another function

Tags: c, malloc, free

Suppose I have a function where I dynamically allocate a 2D array

```
void fun() {
    //does some stuff
    double *matrix[row];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(col * sizeof(double));
    //does some stuff
    free_matrix(matrix);
```

From the function I call another function to free the matrix.

```
void free_matrix(double **matrix, int row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Is deallocating memory like this in another function possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But `free(matrix);` looks wrong as that is not dynamically allocated in the example shown.

Comment: If you know both `row` and `col`, why not `double matrix[row][col];`?

Comment: @Chris That would probably take way more memory on the stack.

Comment: @Gerhardh it definitely would.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with variable declarations and how you call `free_matrix` in your code. Let's fix those first:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun();
void free_matrix(double **matrix, int row);

void fun() {
    const int row = 5;
    const int col = 5;

    double *matrix[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(col * sizeof(double));

    free_matrix(matrix, row);
}

void free_matrix(double **matrix, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }

    free(matrix);
}

int main() {
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but when run:

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You only need to free what you've actually dynamically allocated.

Most of your `free_matrix` functions is fine. For each row in the matrix, you free the dynamically allocated memory. *But* the array of pointers to those rows is *not* dynamically allocated. Trying to free it causes problems.

The fix is simple. Remove that last `free`.

```
void free_matrix(double **matrix, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, dynamically allocate your entire matrix. You can either dynamically allocate your array of row pointers, and then dynamically allocate each row, or dynamically allocate `row * col` elements and do math to access each row/col coordinate.